# Can the same Hyper-V hosts be added to multiple servers running System Center Virtual Machine Manager?

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, hyper-v, system-center, scvmm

I have 2 Hyper-V host servers. One of the hosts is running a guest that runs the current existing System Center Virtual Machine Manager instance for my virtualization setup.

I now have an external server to host the System Center Virtual Machine Manager.

Would there be any problems if I add both of the hosts to the new external server running SCVMM even with them being associated with a different SCVMM?

Ultimately my goal is to mirgate the guest that's running the original SCVMM to the other Hyper-V host and then remove SCVMM from the guest. Or should I remove SCVMM first from the guest, then add the hosts to external server SCVMM and migrate the machine afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having initial feedback to override my concerns of my Hyper-V host disappearing or this being the start of some other arcane quest of repairing my servers by doing this I just started on this from the new VMM host.

After starting the add host configuration I got to a point where it has a checkbox for "reassociate host with this virtual machine manager server" putting this in Google I came across  [How to Reassociate a Host with a VMM Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc956034.aspx) which made me realize that this is a situation that Microsoft planned for.

If you add a Hyper-V host to a 2nd VMM server it will deactivate it from the original VMM server and show it as `Host Not Responding` on the original VMM. At this point if the migration is permanent you could choose to just remove the host from the original VMM.

If you will be returning that Hyper-V host back to the original VMM server all you need to do is "reassociate" the host and it will be controlled by the original VMM server again.

Since my case was pulling my Host from a Guest ran VMM this leaves me with the optimal scenario that I can leave all the configuration in my Guest OS VMM that if for any reason the external VMM cannot be used or crashed that I can have the Hyper-V host take back over for managing itself by just reassociating itself.

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine unless you're using the performance and resource optimization features, but I would not consider it a "supported" configuration.

Is there any reason you cannot remove them from the original SCVMM and then add them with the external server, with no period of overlap? If you're just trying to save time, near 100% of the capabilities of SCVMM can be accessed, although less efficiently, through a combination of the Hyper-V Manager and Failover Cluster Manager, in the case of clustered scenarios.